# Flyway using subdirectories under sql directory with relative path

Tags: flyway

I am currently trying to specify a subdirectory under the sql directory and keep getting an error.  Here is the command I am using:

```
flyway -url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database -schemas=schema1 -locations=sql/schema1 migrate
```

I have tried prefixing with classpath: or filesystem: but was hoping to provide a relative directory so I can move the folder around without breaking the code.

> WARNING: Unable to resolve location classpath:sql/schema1

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can use relative directory paths with the `filesystem:` prefix, as follows.

```
$ mvn flyway:migrate -Dflyway.locations=filesystem:scripts/migration
```